# Merge some MATLAB-related tags

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Can I suggest merging the following tags? Unfortunately I don't have a high enough score in the relevant tags to directly suggest the synonyms (as they have fairly few questions in each, partly because they are split as described below).

<s>[embedded-matlab](/questions/tagged/embedded-matlab) -> [matlab-coder](/questions/tagged/matlab-coder)</s> -- **Completed.**

Embedded MATLAB was a feature of previous versions of MATLAB that has been replaced in recent versions by the MATLAB Coder product. There are only two questions tagged [embedded-matlab](/questions/tagged/embedded-matlab), and both would be just as well described nowadays by [matlab-coder](/questions/tagged/matlab-coder).

<s>[matlab-ide](/questions/tagged/matlab-ide) -> [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) and [matlab-path](/questions/tagged/matlab-path) -> [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab)</s> -- **Completed.**

These tags relate to specific functionalities of MATLAB ([matlab-path](/questions/tagged/matlab-path) a very specific functionality), and they have very few followers. There are 13 and 18 questions for these tags respectively; every one of them is also tagged [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab), and they cover topics that regularly come up on the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) tag in any case.

[matlab-standalone](/questions/tagged/matlab-standalone) -> [matlab-deployment](/questions/tagged/matlab-deployment) and [matlab-compiler](/questions/tagged/matlab-compiler) -> [matlab-deployment](/questions/tagged/matlab-deployment) -- **Could not propose synonym.  [matlab-standalone] is 
already a synonym of [matlab-compiler]**

There are a group of add-on products to MATLAB collectively known (both by users and officially by MathWorks) as deployment products, which produce various standalone components from MATLAB code. These are MATLAB Compiler, MATLAB Builder JA for Java, MATLAB Builder NE for .NET and MATLAB Builder EX for Excel.

The difficulties and questions that arise with the use of these products are all very similar, and they are spread across these tags, splitting their audiences. In addition, the current tag wikis direct users to consider using the [matlab-deployment](/questions/tagged/matlab-deployment) tag rather than [matlab-compiler](/questions/tagged/matlab-compiler) and [matlab-standalone](/questions/tagged/matlab-standalone).

Comment: See my edits...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for the first two. I'm not sure I understand the way tag synonyms work well enough to interpret your third comment - can tags not be put into a mutual cluster of synonyms (standalone = compiler = deployment)? or a chain of synonyms (standalone->compiler->deployment)? Is there another proposal I could make that would solve the issue? Thanks for your advice.